# Calculated column based on What-if parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual in PowerBI that summarizes work hours by employee. The first column shows the employee name.

When training managers on how to use it I want to anonymize by showing employee numbers instead of names.

I tried adding a what-if parameter `Anonymous` with values 0 and 1 and use `IF()` in the DAX of a calculated column but it is not working. It ignores the parameter value.

```
Person = IF(Anonym[Anonym value] = 0; Time[Name]; Time[Empno])
```

will always show Name.

```
Person = IF(Anonym[Anonym value] = 1; Time[Name]; Time[Empno])
```

will always show Empno.

Comment: Calculated columns are computed once, when the data is loaded, and their value doesn't change after that (i.e. when you change the value of the What-if parameter). You must make a measure instead.

Comment: Does not make sense to make a measure out of the names of employees. Is there another solution to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Columns are static. Period. This is the way it works. If you want your calculations to respond to changes (What-if parameters, slicers, etc.), then you must make a measure.

Comment: Andrey is correct. This can't be done in a calculated column. What are you trying to use the column for?

Comment: Instead of employee name, put employee id in the first column. Then, create a measure that depending on the parameter shows either employee name or  a message like "Confidential"

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you really need to use a column and needs it to be "dynamic" is to use a PowerQuery parameter and add a new column based on it and then create your conditional. The downside of this is that you will have to refresh your query everytime you want to change the parameter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).